# Round counter on loop not updating

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript, counter

I'm trying to do something relatively simple, but it appears I'm having one of those of those Mondays. I have a loop 'numLoops' that controls a vast majority of the script in my flash quiz. At the end of each question numLoops triggers and I'm trying to get a visual representation of that. I have a dynamic text box called 'questioncounter' that I can successfully display 'roundcounter'. My problem is however that the text does not seem to update whenever numLoops triggers, it just stays at 1.

At the moment I have

```
var roundcounter:Number = 1;

questioncounter.text = roundcounter.toString();

function addround():void{
    numLoops ++;
    var roundcounter:int = roundcounter ++;
    trace("Round updated")
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: my 'trace' isn't showing up either, so my function clearly isn't triggering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to trim it down even further using my numLoops variable

```
function addround():void{
    numLoops;
    questioncounter.text = (numLoops + 1).toString();
    trace("Round updated")
}
addround();
```

Thanks for your help, your answer gave me this idea!

Answer (score 1):

well the problem is that you are trying to instantiate a Number to a int. This could be possible but than you have to create another variable for the integer. But the easy fix is this:

```
var roundcounter:int = 1;

questioncounter.text = roundcounter.toString();

function addround():void{
    numLoops ++;
    roundcounter ++;
    trace("Round updated")
}
```